# Why kernel 3.6.2 is so much less energy efficient than 3.6.1 on Mint 13?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-mint, power-management

I noticed, that the power consumption in my [ASUS P53E](http://www.asus.com/Commercial_Notebooks/P53_Series/P53E/#specifications) notebook is doubled (from 10W to 20W) when I change from kernel 3.6.1 to 3.6.2 (or later). I use Ubuntu Quantal mainline kernel from [kernel-ppa/mainline - Kernel Ubuntu](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/)
 on Mint 13 Maya (which is based on Ubuntu Precise 12.04).

Please advise me, what additional information I should post, to help you answer.

The power measurements agree with the significant difference in processor temperature (ca. 45 C on 10W and ca. 65 C on 20W), so it is not a glitch of the power meter.

Comment: I noticed the same problem a few days ago, downgrading to an older kernel (3.0.xx, linux-lts on Arch) worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there's a [power utilization regression](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=49031) that was introduced in 3.6.x.  If you can, stick with the older kernel.  Supposedly, there's also an ext4 metadata block corruption bug in 3.6.2 as well, so it might be worth waiting.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an easily reproducible bug between two kernel versions, the best thing to do is use [git bisect to track down the exact cause](http://www.reactivated.net/weblog/archives/2006/01/using-git-bisect-to-find-buggy-kernel-patches/) and then report a bug to whoever made the offending change.

Answer (score 1):

(Even though the question was already answered, am adding this just for the sake of completeness, since it's too big for a comment)

I had the same problem and downgrading to an older kernel solved it.

Investigating further, I found this thread in the Arch forum: [Kernel 3.6.2 Power Regressions (Sandy Bridge)](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1183654).

Appears that [it is a known bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48721#c15), which has already been fixed and the fix will be available in newer versions of the kernel (I don't know if 3.6.4 fixed it).